# NextJS Dynamic routes parameters

Tags: javascript, reactjs, routes, next.js

Is it possible on NextJS to have a dynamic route that will match `/country` and `/country/city`, but will not match `/country/city/whatever_content_here` ? I want to show the same page for both of the above routes, even if I send only the `country` or both the `country` and the `city`.

I know you can do this by using `[...country_city]` but this would also match for example `/country/city/street` which is not the desired functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this is possible.

Look at the api reference here: https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes#catch-all-routes

Based on that you can write logic to check the country_city array and based on that display content

Comment: There is not explained what I was asking. `pages/post/[...slug].js matches /post/a, but also /post/a/b, /post/a/b/c and so on.` In my example I should have a match on `/post/a` and `post/a/b`, but not on `/post/a/b/c` and it should show `Page Not Found`.

Comment: and thats what I responded with. Your query will have a json object like
```json
{ "slug": ["a"] }
```

or 
```json
{ "slug": ["a", "b"] }
```

Based on this it's evident that you can do conditional rendering with simple logic just by evaluating the length of the list?